# SQL 2005 Partitioning

Tags: sql-server-2005, partitioning

I have a database with 200 million records and I need to support 200 write tps. How many partitions do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One. Don't bother. Partitions will slow you down for writes

It's far more important for writes to have a dedicated, fast volume for your transaction log file (the LDF file) for that database alone. Don't add log files either: one LDF on one volume only.

This is because of write ahead logging: [One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259.aspx) and [Two](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230785). Simply, a data page may not be written to disk immediately, but your associated log entry **must** be confirmed as written for any given transaction